# How to integrate Facebook login in Laravel using facebook official login button

Tags: laravel, facebook-login

[Here is Button which i want to integrate with my website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

Comment: Atleast do a google search for asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use laravel socialite. Comes packed with Facebook support out of the box.

https://github.com/laravel/socialite